# Simple point in polygon query at PostGIS & PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, query, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon

Using PostGIS & PostgreSQL (Amazon RDS instance), I need to create a (quite large) table with points (just x, y coordinates)
Then what I need to do is very simple point-in-polygon queries. Points and polygons are in 2D space (not geography types).

I actually managed to do this with [Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/) with this simple query:

```sql
SELECT ST_WITHIN(ST_POINT(x, y), ST_POLYGON('polygon((1  1, 11  44, 44  44, 44 11))'))
FROM "my_table"
```

How it would be possible to have this kind of query working at PostgreSQL?

Comment: Edited the question and removed the extra question

Answer (score 1):

Start with setting up your **RDS with the official guide for PostGIS**
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.PostGIS

use your role (rdsadmin/superuser)

```
create extension postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION
create extension fuzzystrmatch;
CREATE EXTENSION
create extension postgis_tiger_geocoder;
CREATE EXTENSION
create extension postgis_topology;
CREATE EXTENSION
```

Then

```
alter schema tiger owner to rds_superuser;
ALTER SCHEMA
alter schema tiger_data owner to rds_superuser;
ALTER SCHEMA
alter schema topology owner to rds_superuser;
ALTER SCHEMA
```

Then check your connection

```
psql --host xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.us-xxxx-x.rds.amazonaws.com (or IP)
--port 5432
--username rds_superuser
--password xxxxxxxxxxxx
--dbname gis
```

In QGIS you can connect and with the **right privileges** you can save to that location.
via **SSH Tunnel** https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/hc/en-us/articles/205408088-Access-Your-Database-Remotely-Through-an-SSH-Tunnel